# Concurrency problem using spring, dbcp and postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql, concurrency, apache-commons-dbcp

The software stack I'm using is: tomcat->spring-> hibernate-> DBCP -> postgreSQL

I have a query that search for some data using a column of type "timestamp without time zone".

If the application is tested in a single user mode, then there are no problems.

I'm using [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) to make some stress test and can see that sometimes the query failed. This can only be reproduced if several users are accessing the application at the same time (more than 20 in the same second).

The error is something like:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: timestamp out of range: "20120100-09-26 00:00:00.000000 -04:00:00"

org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2062)
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1795)
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:479)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:367)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:271)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1808)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67)

The versions that I'm using are:

- tomcat 6.0.26
- spring 3
- DBCP 1.4
- postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar
- PostgreSQL Version: 8.4.4-0ubuntu10.04

Answer (score 2):

In your java code do you have non-threadsafe usage of a DateFormat object anywhere?  Weird and wonderful date errors often stem from this sort of issue?

```
private static final DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

becomes

```
private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> fmt = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
    @Override
    protected DateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    }
}
```

See [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

Comment: tks for the answer. The code runs inside inside a method and it only use variables declared in the method.

Comment: Take a look at p7spy - http://www.p6spy.com/ - you can set it up as a proxy JDBC driver to log all statements running against the db - should help you pinpoint the exact query that's causing the problem, and potentially find where the statements called from.

Answer (score 1):

> timestamp out of range:
>   "20120100-09-26 00:00:00.000000
>   -04:00:00"

You're working in the year 20120100 ? (twenty million) Are you sure? The maximum year for a timestamp is 294276, but I'm pretty sure your input isn't correct.

This has nothing to do with concurrency either, just out of range input.

Comment: that's the weird thing. I have a jmeter test that that queries some data using the timestamp. If the number of user are less than 20, then there are no problem. I start increasing the number of user and the problem appears from time to time.

Comment: Then the problem might be in JMeter: it's using invalid data, the database has no other option than to reject the query and throw an error.